# Set an element of an array of *char as NULL in C

Tags: arrays, c, null

I have the task of going through a binary search tree and collecting the keys in every node and storing them in an array. After this, I have to set the last element of this array as NULL. This is all done inside a function, which then returns this array of *char.

I believe the part about collecting the keys and storing them in the array is working well, as I've tested that enough. However, I'm not able to define the last element of the array as NULL correctly. I thought it should be done like this:

`list_keys[tree_size(tree)] = NULL;`

However, after some printf's, I realized that this was cleaning my tree. When I print tree_size(tree) before this line, it gives me the size of the tree correctly. However, when I do it after that line, it gives me 0. I don't believe that the problem is in the function `tree_size()` because when I attempt to access an element of the tree before that line, it works well, but after the line, I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error, probably due to trying access something that doesn't exist anymore.

I have no idea what's wrong, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The `tree` is of the type `tree_t` and it's defined as:

```c
struct tree_t {
    struct entry_t *entry;
    struct tree_t *right_child;
    struct tree_t *left_child;
};
```

The `tree_size()` is defined as:

```c
int tree_size(struct tree_t *tree) {
    if (tree->entry != NULL) {
        //if two children exist
        if (tree->left_child != NULL && tree->right_child != NULL) {
            return 1 + tree_size(tree->left_child) + tree_size(tree->right_child);
        }
        //there's a right child and there isnt a left child
        if (tree->right_child != NULL && tree->left_child == NULL) {
            return 1 + tree_size(tree->right_child);
        }
        //there's a left child and there isnt a right child
        if (tree->left_child != NULL && tree->right_child == NULL) {
            return 1 + tree_size(tree->left_child);
        }
        //there are no children
        if (tree->left_child == NULL && tree->right_child == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }
      }
    //if the entry is empty
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, what I'm doing right now is:

First, I define `list_keys` and allocate memory:

```
char **list_keys;
list_keys = (char *)malloc((tree_size(tree)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

Then, I call an auxiliary function `tree_get_keys_aux(tree, list_keys, 0)` that will do the initial part I mentioned. It is defined as:

```
void tree_get_keys_aux(struct tree_t *tree, char **list_keys, int index) {
  //N
  list_keys[index] = (char *)malloc((strlen(tree->entry->key))*sizeof(char)); //allocating memory for each string that I want to add to the list
  strcpy(list_keys[index],tree->entry->key); //copying the content

  index = index + 1;

  //L
  if (tree->left_child != NULL) {
    tree_get_keys_aux(tree->left_child, list_keys, index);
  }

  //R
  if (tree->right_child != NULL) {
    tree_get_keys_aux(tree->right_child, list_keys, index);
  }

  return;

}
```

Then, I do the line that's bringing me problems,

```
list_keys[tree_size(tree)] = NULL;
```

And lastly,

```
return list_keys;
```

Comment: We don't know how you are implementing the tree. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MikeCAT Okay let me add the implementation! Thank you

Comment: *"I don't believe that the problem is in the function tree_size()"* - and then you add that function? Why? Where do you believe the error is? Please, post a [mre].

Comment: How is `list_keys` declared and updated?

Comment: Your `tree_size()` function can be simplified a lot by allowing it to recurse with the null pointers: `int tree_size(struct tree_t *tree) { if (tree->entry != NULL) return 1 + tree_size(tree->left_child) + tree_size(tree->right_child); return 0; }`

Comment: @IanAbbott You have to check if `tree` is not `NULL` for that.

Comment: @MikeCAT I'm sorry, let me add how I'm doing it!

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes, good point! So change it to `if (tree != NULL && tree->entry != NULL) ...`.

Comment: Is it possible to have a tree node with `entry` null, but `left_child` and/or `right_child` non-null?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I can't figure out what's wrong and, even though I believe that function is working properly, something could've slipped my attention and the problem could indeed be there. I just wanted to provide as much information as I have.

Comment: @IanAbbott The exercise I'm doing isn't very clear about that. I think it is possible but it's not going to happen.

Comment: 1. You don't allocated for terminating null-characters and you have to allocate for that. 2. `tree_get_keys_aux` won't recognize the number of data for left child and they may be overwritten in by data from the right child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,

```
list_keys = (char *)malloc((tree_size(tree)+1)*sizeof(char));
```

is wrong. The elements are `char*`, so you have to allocate for that or you will cause out-of-range access.

It should be:

```
list_keys = malloc((tree_size(tree)+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

or

```
list_keys = malloc((tree_size(tree)+1)*sizeof(*list_keys));
```

See also: [c - Do I cast the result of malloc? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Secondly,

```
  list_keys[index] = (char *)malloc((strlen(tree->entry->key))*sizeof(char)); //allocating memory for each string that I want to add to the list
  strcpy(list_keys[index],tree->entry->key); //copying the content
```

is wrong. You have to allocate one more element for terminating null-character.

It should be:

```
  list_keys[index] = malloc((strlen(tree->entry->key) + 1)*sizeof(char)); //allocating memory for each string that I want to add to the list
  strcpy(list_keys[index],tree->entry->key); //copying the content
```

Thirdly, `tree_get_keys_aux` is not recoginizing number of elements in left child and data from left child will be overwritten by data from right child.
To avoid this overwriting, you can use `tree_size` to determint the tree size and advance `index` according to that.

```
  //L
  if (tree->left_child != NULL) {
    tree_get_keys_aux(tree->left_child, list_keys, index);
    index += tree_size(tree->left_child); // add this
  }

  //R
  if (tree->right_child != NULL) {
    tree_get_keys_aux(tree->right_child, list_keys, index);
  }
```

Comment: Nice usage of `list_keys = malloc((tree_size(tree)+1)*sizeof(*list_keys));`

Comment: Thank you so much! Your suggestions really helped!! I only had to add `if (tree-> left_child != NULL)` before increasing the index and now it works perfectly.